# Aggregate column name

Tags: r, aggregate

I am using the `aggregate()` function which takes a dataframe called `dupl`, aggregates against 2 columns named `interval` and `day type` and by doing so it also takes the mean of another column named `steps`.

I would like the column containing the means be named `steps_mean`. I use this code:

```r
aggr <- aggregate(dupl$steps, by=dupl[c("interval","daytype")], FUN=(mean_steps=mean) )
```

However the column in the output is named `x` instead of `mean_steps`.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
aggregate(dupl, by=list(dupl$interval, dupl$daytype), FUN="mean")
```